# android lint still give "Call requires API ..." error after I put check there

Tags: android, android-lint

I have the following code:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1){
     enter_pos.callOnClick();
}
```

But I still get error from Lint:

```
Call requires API level 15 (current min is 12): android.widget.Button#callOnClick
```

Why Lint is still giving error even after I put a check for the API version? I am using

```
Android Developer Tools
Build: v22.0.5-757759
```

Under Windows 8. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: sugestion, clean rebuild project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` above the method you are using this. Lint cannot decide if you do your check right by looking at your code

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse Window -> preferences -> Android  -> Lint error checking  uncheck the two check boxes and apply changes and then clean the project.